# how to get the total size of certain folders in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

How can I get the total size of the certain folders?

For example I have a list of specific folder names in users.txt

```
# cat users.txt
user1
user2
user3
```

all this folders are locate in /home/

I have tried to execute:

```
# for i in `cat users.txt`; do du -shc /home/$i/; done
3.9M    /home/user1/
3.9M    total
141M    /home/user2/
141M    total
75M /home/user3/
75M total
```

but I need a total size of all of this folders.

Comment: Consider posting your question in: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
du -shc $(sed 's@^@/home/@' users.txt)
```

That uses the contents of `users.txt`, prepended with `/home/`, as the arguments to `du`, so it will sum them for you.

Comment: To my understanding, the file contains only the usernames, not the full path.

Comment: @alfasin: thank you, I missed that part.  Fixed now.

Comment: @John Zwinck: thanks, that exactly what I need!

Comment: Under recent [tag:bash], you could `du -chs /home/{tom,sarah,user{1,2,3}}`

Answer (score -1):

You can pass output of du to tail -n 1 or execute

```
du -s directory
```

To get only size you can do

```
du -s directory | cut -f1
```

Comment: Probably I don't fully understand problem, so  I get negative karma.